# Get google search results in java without being flagged

Tags: java, google-search

I have a one time task where I need to query google programmatically. 
However I don't want to trouble google and get my code flagged as a bot. 
Does anyone know the criteria that google uses to detect bots? Is it possible to issue queries at intervals or in smaller batches and work around the problem? 
I only need about 3000 queries to get my work done.

Comment: If you're using their APIs they have documentation on how many queries you can make. [This answer has more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405942/google-search-api-site-limit)

Answer (score 1):

Well, most software catch bots by using

- time scale (you can't search different things with frequency 5 ms for example)
- your network gateway (aka IP).

For example google maps, foursquare, yahoo .... have access 1k-10k per day from the same external IP.

Comment: So if I issued queries at intervals of say 5 secs then would that work?